# Laravel Deploy on ubuntu

Tags: apache, laravel, ubuntu, laravel-5

I am trying to deploy a laravel script on a ubuntu server but have 2 problems.
1-how to remove public from url(from myip/laravel/public/myURL to myip/laravel/myURl) 
2-how to protect other file(if a make a get request myip/laravel/.env it show all the content of .env file) 
Thank you

Comment: Make sure `mod_rewrite` is enabled

Comment: Here is the tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-laravel-with-an-nginx-web-server-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you checkout the documentation page on [web server configuration](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/installation#web-server-configuration).

It gives you suggestion on how to setup Laravel on your server.

Basic steps

1) Put your laravel app in a specific folder

2) Point your webserver document root at your_app/public

3) Ensure RWX permissions are correct on the folders.

Especially point 2 will make sure that you cannot call .env file...

Answer (score 0):

For the first issue:

If you are using apache2 on your ubuntu server, first, you have to put the laravel files at /var/www/html, to be able change the document root. Then open your /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf (Or whatever file your default site configuration is) look for

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
```

and replace it with 
`DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public`. This points it to the public folder of `var/www/html` which should be where your project is.

For the second:
In your `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` file change 
`Options Indexes` under the `<Directory>` tag to `Options -Indexes`. And finally run 
`sudo a2dismod autoindex`.

This should fix your problems for an apache server. Don't forget to restart you apache2 server with `sudo service apache2 restart`.

Answer (score -1):

You have to put laravel public folder files in www folder and rest are before www folder.